# Express app not firing proxy

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, http-proxy

I'm currently building an express app that uses webpack and in order to avoid duplicate files being created (multiple indexes etc.) I'm sending bundled webpack assets through a proxy.

I have the following route:

```
app.all('/assets/*', function (req, res) {
        console.log('foo');
        proxy.web(req, res, {
          target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001'
        });
    });
```

The `foo`statement is triggered when I visit `http://localhost:3000/assets/` but NOT when I visit `http://localhost:3000/assets/styles.css`

Even weirder, when I change my SASS files to generate a new `styles.css` and visit `http://localhost:3001/assets/styles.css` the updated CSS is present but not when visiting the same file on `:3000` (which I guess kinda makes sense if the proxy isn't being fired...)

I'm not gonna lie, this is seriously freaking me out and some hair is about to get pulled out :)

Comment: Can you show your other middleware you're using? It's possible that something else is handling that request before it makes it to this one.

Comment: ^ I.e., your sass middleware might be intercepting and handling the request before it makes it to this one.

Comment: There actually isn't any other than my bundler process (which commented out still has the same issue)... I'm at bare-bones app stage pretty much.

Comment: Hmm, it might still be useful to see your other code. You have to at least have some sort of a static file handler in there if the .css files are getting served up at all. I can't say for certain that's what's interfering without seeing more code, though.

Comment: I know this is probably a little cheeky, but here's the repo: https://leaky@bitbucket.org/leaky/webpack-express.git

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join('./app/www')));` might be your problem. Is there an actual `/assets/` folder inside of `./app/www`?

Comment: There was indeed... A sneaky command of 'webpack' must have occured at some point creating the 'hard' files. i've no idea why I didn't even think to check that... It's obviously time to sleep. Thanks bro!